# ¿Paréntesis que falta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy ingresando `HTML` desde `JS`, pero a través de `ajax` traigo consultas que contienen datos, por ende se crean arreglos, los cuales estoy pasando como parámetros para una función. 
El problema es que me da un error por falta de paréntesis o llaves pero no comprendo mi error de sintaxis, seria de gran ayuda si alguien me logra decir donde y porque existe este error?

```js
  $(document).on('click', '#boton_asignar', function traer_comuna() {
    var select = $('#ejecutivos option:selected').text();
    if (select == '--') {
      msg_box_alert('0', 'Seleccione un ejecutivo', 'No hay ejecutivos seleccionados');
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/traer_comuna',
        data: $('#form_usuario').serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
          if (json.success == 1) {
            var comunasNoAsignadas = json.comunasNoAsignadas;
            var comunasAsignadas = json.comunasAsignadas;
            var valor = json.valor;
            var user = $('#name').val();
            var mostrarTodo = $('<!-- Default box --><div class="box animated fadeIn" id="caja_secundaria"><!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) --><div class="nav-tabs-custom"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-rigth"><li class="active"><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab"><label for="">' + user + '</label></a></li><li class="pull-left header"></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1"><div class="row">  <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-4"><label for="">Usuarios no asignados</label><table id="comunasNoAsignadas" class="table table-bordered"><form id="idBtn"></table></div><div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-4"><label for="">Usuarios asignados</label><table id="comunasAsignadas" class="table table-bordered"></table><form></div></div></div><!-- /.tab-pane --></div></div></div>');
            if ($('#caja_secundaria').length > 0) {
              $('#caja_secundaria').remove();
              $('#mostrarDatos').prepend(mostrarTodo);
            } else {
              $('#mostrarDatos').prepend(mostrarTodo);
            }
            var user_id = $('#usuario').val();
            for (var i = 0; i < comunasNoAsignadas.length; i++) {
              $('#comunasNoAsignadas').append('<tr><td><a data-placement="top" title="Asignar Supervisión" id="' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][0] + '" onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+","+user_id +')" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i></a></td><td class="opcion" value="' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + '">' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + '</td></tr>');
            }
            if (comunasAsignadas != undefined) {
              for (var i = 0; i < comunasAsignadas.length; i++) {
                $('#comunasAsignadas').append('<tr><td><a data-placement="top" title="Quitar Supervisión"  class="btn btn-danger btn-md btnDesasignar" id="' + comunasAsignadas[i][0] + '" onclick="quitar_supervision("' + comunasAsignadas[i][2] + '")" ><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i></a></td><td class="opcion" value="' + comunasAsignadas[i][2] + '">' + comunasAsignadas[i][2] + '</td></tr> ');
              }
            }
            // AQUI PONER EL ELSE DE LA WEA
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
          msg_box_alert(xhr.responsetext);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Este es el error cuando doy click en el boton al lado izquierdo de la comuna:**

[image: Error por boton]

**Al parecer el error esta en la declaracion de esta funcion:**

```
$('#comunasNoAsignadas').append('<tr><td><a data-placement="top" title="Asignar Supervisión" id="' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][0] + '" onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+","+user_id +')" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i></a></td><td class="opcion" value="' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + '">' + comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + '</td></tr>');
```

para ser mas especifico, esta aquí:

```
onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+","+user_id +')"
```

pero no logro notar cual es el error de sintaxis.

**Esto es lo que se crea en el HTML:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ya checaste si el código fuente HTML generado es el que buscas? Dale click derecho -> ver código fuente (o alguna opción parecida) y checa si el atributo es generado correctamente.

Comment: si es generado correctamente, muestro una foto en la pregunta con el codigo fuente de lo que crea.

Comment: revisa las correcciones que te muestro en la respuesta , si persiste el error avisa

Comment: as una prueba, pon `onclick="function(){alert("hola mundo")}"` en los onclick , para descartar el resto del código y estar seguro que es ahí

Comment: @felipeandrade por cierto, esos onclick estan mal, si es un texto (string) el que se mete como parametro, debería ir entrecomillado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como has dicho:

```
onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+","+user_id +')"
```

Estas confundiendo las comillas simples por las dobles. Estas cosas pegandolas en el notepad se ven facil :)

```
onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+','+user_id +')"
```

```js
var i = 0;
var comunasNoAsignadas = [["Cerrillos",5875,"JONATHAN ACEITON UGAS"]];
var user_id = 131231;

console.log(comunasNoAsignadas[i][0]);
console.log(comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]);

$('#comunasNoAsignadas').append(
 '<tr><td><a data-placement="top" title="Asignar Supervisión" id="' + 
 comunasNoAsignadas[i][0] + 
 '" onclick=\'asignar_supervision("' +
 comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] +
 '","' +
 user_id +
 '")\' class="btn btn-success btn-md" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i></a></td><td class="opcion" value="' + 
 comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + 
 '">' + 
 comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + 
 '</td></tr>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="comunasNoAsignadas"></table>

<tr><td><a data-placement="top" title="Asignar Supervisión" id="A" onclick="asignar_supervision(B,1)" class="btn btn-success btn-md" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i></a></td><td class="opcion" value="C">D</td></tr>
```

Comment: Es el mismo codigo que tengo, sigue apareciendo el mismo error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @felipeandrade ¿has probado a cambiarle las dobles por las simples?

Comment: si, pero lamentablemente e estado pegado en este error hace 4 horas y estoy estancado se me acaban las ideas.

Comment: ¿Y la asignación del array? Aqui en el ejemplo hace bien el append. ¿Has mirado que sea en otro lado?

Comment: @felipeandrade que tipo de valores traen los arrays comunasNoAsignadas[i][0]

Comment: traen un ID, que es un numero

Comment: @felipeandrade no traen un ID, almenos en tu pantallazo es texto. Y ese texto tiene que ir entrecomillado para meterlo como parametro. Escapa las comillas para que no se te machaquen. Echale un ojo al cambio. De todas maneras, le das un onclick al a? ¿Por qué no a la celda que lo contiene?

Comment: Gracias!, lograste solucionar mi problema, hacían falta backslash para traer los parametros

Answer (score 0):

cuando declaras

```
$(document).on('click', '#boton_asignar', function traer_comuna() {...}
```

no le pongas nombre a la función, la función debe ser anónima y se dispara cuando se realiza en el evento, esa es tu función **callback**, la declararías así:

```
$(document).on('click', '#boton_asignar', function() { ... }
```

Tienes un onclick que llama a **asignar_supervision**, al cual le pasas **comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]** en su estado normal , y luego en el otro onclick el **quitar_supervision** le pasas **comunasAsignadas[i][2]** pero tratándolo de convertir a `string`, revisa el escape de las doble y simples comillas que puede que al querer convertir a `string`, te de conflicto con las que tenga o pueda tener ya el valor y te estés saltando algún paréntesis sin querer.

cuando utilizas comillas simples para abrir las cadenas , no las juntes con las dobles , porque estarias escapando caracteres , si tienes

```
onclick="asignar_supervision('+comunasNoAsignadas[i][2]+","+user_id +')"
```

la **,**(coma) la estas insertando para separar argumentos pero utilizando las comillas dobles , usa las simples como mismo iniciaste la cadena, quedándote así:

```
onclick="asignar_supervision('+ comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + ',' + user_id +')"
```

Comment: La tengo con nombre, ya que no solo se dispara al momento de hacer click, si no que también se dispara cuando se cambian ciertos parámetros en la pagina, por eso la tengo con nombre, No se si sera una buena practica

Comment: bueno mientras no te cause problemas , puedes dejarla así , pero lo normal es crearla anónima , para el evento click de algún botón

Comment: onclick="asignar_supervision('+ comunasNoAsignadas[i][2] + '","' + user_id +')"

asignando esa linea de codigo se rompe los parametros que se pasan a la funcion y solo muestra el primer parametro

Comment: ya lo arregle es que me confundí y no borre las doble comillas que tenia , gracias por corregir

Comment: Los parametros pasan de forma correcta pero sigue mostrandome el error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list al momento de hacer un click en los botones que se crean